# How to add Advenced Custom Fields In Single Post

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I Need Help, I add ACF code in single post download button showing but in link of download button same of link post, I add other website and link in button download always same, what's wrong in my code or is there something missing so that ACF doesn't work

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
< div class="site-wrapper <?php if(!has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>f-width<?php endif; ?>">  
    < div class="container site-content">
        < div class="wp-block-button is-style-outline"><a class="wp-block-button__link" href="<?php the_field('linkid'); ?>">Download Now</a></div>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part('content'); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>      
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: <?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="site-wrapper <?php if(!has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>f-width<?php endif; ?>"> 
 <div class="container site-content">
<div class="wp-block-button is-style-outline"><a class="wp-block-button__link" href="<?php the_field('linkid'); ?>">Download Now</a></div>
   <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part('content'); ?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
   
   <?php endif; ?>

 </div>  
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

Comment: if your comment above is the correct solution and works for you, you can post it as an answer to your own question and that way it's formatted nicely and future searches will help others find the answer. :-)